# Missing modules using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

### Description

I'm trying to build an `.exe` using `cx_Freeze` but doing `py setup.py build` I receive the following errors, the `.exe` is created but it doesn't start
(I'm using `Python 3.6` and latest version of `cx_Freeze`).

Log:

```
Missing modules:
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from http.server, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? termios imported from tty
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
creating directory build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib
```

### Question

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: "This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform" you generally get those and I doubt that error is the problem.  What errors occurred when you ran your exe through command prompt?